# Connection freeze ubuntu 20.04 lts desktop sharing

Tags: networking

Hi my  problem is that when I use vncviewer(mac) to connect to my ubuntu 20.04 lts the wifi connection freeze I have to disconnet my wifi dongle on ubuntu to make my wifi connection on ubuntu again.To clarify mac viever ubuntu server thanks

Comment: thanks is a ubuntu pc that I use as media server connected to my tv so it's a ubuntu desktop

Comment: ok I don't  know what to say.I have a pc with ubuntu desktop installed.I use vnc on my mac to control  ubuntu 20.04 lts but usually after 10 seconds that i use screen sharing it freeze and i have to disconnect the uds dongle and reconnect

Comment: nothing noboby can help me?

Comment: thanks done  I use the 20.04 lts.I have no idea what the kernel is can you please help me,i'm just a user

Comment: can someone please give me some kind of feedback

Comment: very helpful resources here lol